# ERROR with "Failed to set locale, defaulting to C" on Centos at the docker environment (yum install)

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, centos8

The docker has released a new version of centos 8, so I try to use it with Dockerfile to build a new environment but I got some error message

Dockerfile content

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install
```

when I ran the above command, it got an error.

so I am going to the container and try to use a command line to check what is going on, and then I found the error when I try to use the command line "yum install" as the following picture.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a good method to handle this issue, please follow the code to install the package "glibc-langpack-en" in your environment or put the command line in your dockerfile.

Dockerfile content

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y glibc-langpack-en
```

Centos shell script

```
sudo yum install -y glibc-langpack-en
```

[image]

Comment: `yum install -y glibc-langpack-en` this worked for me on Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 12):

you should set `LANG` and `LC_ALL/LC_CTYPE` variables before run `yum update`.

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=C
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3):

#Set

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
```

#check

```
$ printenv | grep LC
```

LC_ALL=C
#Try again

```
$ sudo yum check
```

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
check all

Answer (score 0):

as root user, then do steps:

1. sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
2. sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
3. sudo yum update -y